# How is the best_score_ attribute of RandomizedSearchCV calculated?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

so I just ran into an issue when trying to validate the `best_score_` value for my grid search.

I just ran a RandomizedSearchCV, and got `best_score_=0.05325203252032521`.Then I tried to calculate this value manually, based on the information contained inside the RandomizedSearchCV object. What I did was:

```
print(best_model_idx)

results_in_splits = []

for k, v in cv.cv_results_.items():
    if 'split' in k:
        print('\t->', k)
        results_in_splits.append(v[best_model_idx])
    else:
        print(k)

print('\n')
print(sum(results_in_splits) / len(results_in_splits))
print(cv.best_score_)
```

This yielded the following output:

```
0
mean_fit_time
std_fit_time
mean_score_time
std_score_time
param_subsample
param_n_estimators
param_min_child_weight
param_max_depth
param_gamma
param_colsample_bytree
params
    -> split0_test_score
    -> split1_test_score
    -> split2_test_score
    -> split3_test_score
    -> split4_test_score
    -> split5_test_score
    -> split6_test_score
    -> split7_test_score
    -> split8_test_score
    -> split9_test_score
    -> split10_test_score
    -> split11_test_score
    -> split12_test_score
mean_test_score
std_test_score
rank_test_score
```

As you can see we obtain a different result (0.046 vs 0.053) and in some other experiments, this change is even more drastic.

Can anyone help me clear this up? It would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue. Have tried with `iris` data and with dummy data from several configurations of `make_classification`; every single time the result of your posted code is identical with `cv_best_score_`. Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Thanks a lot man, you are an absolute legend for even taking the time to help me. To address your questions:

* there are 13 folds;

* now that I've confirmed that something is afoot, I will try to make a minimal working example. I didn't start with that because the data is confidential so it might take a little bit of time.

However, I can guarantee that the object that I am analyzing is the unaltered output of RandomizedSearchCV. I am using parallelism and my model is XGBClassifier, and I am also manually setting the folds.

Comment: Hey, so here's a minimal reproducible example: https://pastebin.com/Ebd6Xd45. All the data is written in the code so no need to load up any external files.
I used the accuracy as a scoring metric this time (instead of a custom function we were using, which would've made it more complicated to explain the code - basically we were using precision @ 30), so the difference between both values isn't as large, BUT it still exists and I don't think it's small enough that it can be explained as a numerical rounding error.

Comment: You will need to install Pandas, Numpy and xgboost though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: As per OP's comment below, upgrading scikit-learn from v0.21.3 to v0.22.2 resolved the issue.

---

As I already mentioned in the comments, I have been **unable to reproduce** your issue, either with the `iris` data or with dummy data from several configurations of scikit-learn's [`make_classification`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_classification.html).

Running the whole script (code + data) you have posted at [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Ebd6Xd45) does not change this; here are the last lines of your own code:

```
results_in_splits = []

for k, v in cv.cv_results_.items():
    if 'split' in k:
        print('\t->', k)
        results_in_splits.append(v[best_model_idx])
    else:
        print(k)

print('\n')
print(sum(results_in_splits) / len(results_in_splits))
print(cv.best_score_)
```

the output being

```
mean_fit_time
std_fit_time
mean_score_time
std_score_time
param_subsample
param_n_estimators
param_min_child_weight
param_max_depth
param_gamma
param_colsample_bytree
params
    -> split0_test_score
    -> split1_test_score
    -> split2_test_score
    -> split3_test_score
    -> split4_test_score
    -> split5_test_score
    -> split6_test_score
    -> split7_test_score
    -> split8_test_score
    -> split9_test_score
    -> split10_test_score
    -> split11_test_score
    -> split12_test_score
mean_test_score
std_test_score
rank_test_score


0.8926320979964705
0.8926320979964705
```

i.e. apparently the two scores are identical, as they should be.

The almost identical scores in your CV splits, discussed in the comments of the other answer here, are also not a bug or anything, just an artifact of an unfortunate situation: too small a dataset (678 samples) combined with too many CV splits (13) leads to your validation samples being only 13-14 for each split; any statistic calculated on so few samples is spurious and should not be relied upon.

But this last observation is actually irrelevant to your main question here: what you report is **not reproducible** under a variety of situations, including the script and data provided by yourself.

Comment: I upgraded scikit-learn from scikit-learn==0.21.3 to 0.22.2, and the problem is fixed (got the same output as you).

Answer (score 2):

RandomizedSearchCV tries to find best parameters for your model. To do this, for different parameter combination it trains your model again and again with cross validation and calculate the mean score of cross-validation for each parameter setup.

Then it checks the highest mean cross-validated score and return the best parameters and best score of your model.

In a summary:

- It tries `N` different parameter combination on your dataset.
- For each parameter combination, it trains model with cross-validation.
- Then it takes the average of each fold in cross-validation and then assign that score to responsible parameter combination.
- Then looks all results and select the highest one.
- Finally it returns, the best score, best model, best parameters etc..

Comment: Totally agree with you! But if that's the case, why couldn't I manually calculate the best_score_ based on the mean score of the best model across all the folds? Shouldn't the two values be equal?

Comment: Could you please check the values of the dictionary that you iterate? There should be different values which includes `split` keyword like `split0_test_score` and like `split_0_training_score` etc.. It will be good if you edit your question and print `k` and `v` value for each iteration.

Comment: I am printing k already, not sure if that's what you mean? The only things that show up are the splitN_test_score keys.

Comment: Edited to show the keys (printing the values would result in too much output). 
I am working on a minimal reproducible example, what is the best way for me to share the inputs? Can I zip them and upload them here?

Comment: Hey, here's a pastebin with the output you mentioned: https://pastebin.com/nBVP0G7J
(for all key/values pairs inside cv_results_)

Comment: Another interesting point is that all scores for your each split_test_score is same. Ex: split11_test_score = [0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 ....]. This is same for each split which seems have some problem. Also in some splits, score comes for 0 which also another interesting thing. Your model seems suffer from underfitting.

Comment: Yes, this is just a minimal example to show the bug. I removed all feature columns except for one, although the problem persists when I use all columns. It's normal that it's underfitting with only one feature :P